# solving 3 unknown with 2 equations in Natural numbers

Tags: logarithms

Iam trying to solve $a^b = f_1$ , $a^c = f_2$, I know the answer will get infinite set of answers.
but can I solve it in Natural numbers , hence $a$, $b$, $c$, $f_1$, $f_2$ are natural numbers and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are known ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $f_1$, and $p^n$ the greatest power of $p$ dividing $f_1$. Similarly, let $m$ be the greatest power of $p$ dividing $f_2$. Let $g = \gcd(m,n)$. Then *if* $f_1$ and $f_2$ can be written in the form you've stated, then $a = f_1^{g/n}, b = n/g, c = m/g.$

Alternatively, if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are of that form, then $\log f_1/\log f_2$ is a rational number. Find it in lowest terms using e.g. continued fractions; it's then $b/c$. Finally, set $a=f_1^{1/b}$.

Comment: This will get one answer.  Then if the $a$ you find is a power, you can use the laws of exponents to find some more.  For example, if $a=d^2$, then $d^{2b}=f_1, d^{2c}=f_2$ is another.

Comment: how to get the prime dividing of f1, how to get p ?

Comment: @Max You will need to use a factorization algorithm; for instance, if $f_1$ is not too large, trial division.